# What is Passport Number in Appointment Letter for?

Tags: job-offer, human-resources, visa, singapore

I am applying an abroad company and they offer me to become their employee, **without** send me any offer letter or other letter, only by conversation in email.

Then, they ask whether they can proceed to apply working visa for me. I feel this is unusual, so I ask for job agreement letter prior to proceed applying working visa to evade any disadvantageous things in future.

It seems that their HR now finally wants to make the job agreement letter for me. However, the HR says that she need my passport number for appointment letter (which I assume it is a different letter than the job offer letter) and asks me for my passport number. Since passport number is very private information, can anyone advise what exactly passport number in appointment letter for?

**Update**:

I have got the Appointment Letter from HRD. In this letter, it consists the sections similar with job agreement with sections, for example, salary, duties, working hours, etc, etc, and she put the field of passport number under Employee's Acknowledgement which this section is right after my user's (manager) name.

So I assume this is safe to write down my passport number there.

Comment: Where are you located? Are you a foreigner in your location?

Comment: I am applying for company located in Singapore and I am foreigner to SG, but currently my location is in my birth country.

Comment: Related: http://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/50336/head-hunter-agency-asking-for-passport

Comment: You are a foreigner in Singapore. Why would you feel this is unusual when they told you to apply work visa for you?

Comment: scaaahu: It's because I have asked some of my friends there and they got the letter prior to apply for work visa. Jan: I have read that thread, the root case is same but different scenario..

Comment: I would assume that they want to construct a legally binding offer tied to you individually, for which they want a passport number as your name isn't unique. Regardless, only the company involved can answer your questions about this, we can't provide a useful answer here.

Comment: If you're a foreigner, it seems normal that a company would need your passport in order to apply for a visa for you. In fact, maybe it was just unusual that the friends you talked to *didn't* need their passport.

Comment: _they got the letter prior to apply for work visa._ Did you ever ask them whether their offer letters contain their passport numbers?

Comment: Lilienthal: It seems so..  Brandin: Yes but I believe that the visa application must be after job offer/agreement. scaaahu: Yes indeed.

Comment: @JonW Well, they *did* give you an offer, if only verbally/e-mail/unofficially. I understand your issue of privacy, but if you're not forthcoming with the information they need (or the info they *believe* they need), they may interpret this as reluctance to take their offer. You could do both - send them your passport number and then ask for a date on when you can expect the offer letter.

Comment: @JonW Congratulations on your offer. I'm assuming you already did your due diligence in verifying that the company was authentic but if not, make sure you check them out thoroughly first. Aside from that, as a general pointer: to reply to people in the comments, use an @ and then their username (press Tab to auto-complete the given suggestions). This will alert that user via a notification.

Answer (score 2):

Realistically they do need your passport number for a work visa in Singapore, more info [here](http://www.mom.gov.sg/passes-and-permits)

Reasons why someone would want a passport number for underhand purposes are mostly to do with identity theft, A persons passport number can be used to collect a lot of information about them. Full names, date of birth, place of birth, and of course nationality. Knowing these can make finding more information lot easier. Faking a passport can let someone open bank accounts and all sorts of potentially messy things.

But in light of your update everything looks normal, and I wouldn't worry about it. And instead focus on getting prepared for your new job.

Comment: Hi Kilisi, thanks, actually this is the process before visa application, which is both side agreement on my job position. Btw, I have edited my post :)

Comment: @JonW With the additional information, yes it all seems ok to me. Good luck on your new job

Answer (score 1):

Your passport number really isn't private information.  Most jobs will ask for a copy to prove who you are.  Most hotels will take a photocopy when you stay.  If you ever use your passport to get into a bar or club - they have a copy.

Now, all that said, this still sounds a little dodgy.  I would contact an employment organisation in SG and ask them if this is usual practice.  You could also contact the SG embassy in your country and ask how you apply for a visa - they may be able to explain what is happening.

Comment: *Most jobs will ask for a copy to prove who you are* and *Most hotels will take a photocopy when you stay*. That depends on the country. In my country (The Netherlands) that last action is illegal.

Comment: @JanDoggen Casinos do it, at least, in the Netherlands (but only if you don't have another id).

Comment: I do agree with you. In SG, hotel and casino ask someone's passport before allow him/her to enter. Btw, I have edited my post :)

Comment: @Jonast92 I know, even hotels still do it. https://www.rijksoverheid.nl/onderwerpen/paspoort-en-identificatie/vraag-en-antwoord/wie-mag-vragen-naar-mijn-identiteitsbewijs-en-wanneer